# Java Decorator for NotEmpty on an Optional

Tags: java, jackson, dropwizard

Is there a decorator equivalent of `@NotEmpty` but one that works on `Optional`? Basically I have a property

```
Optional<String> voice;
```

And I don't want it to ever be an empty string; either `!voice.isPresent()` or if it is, it is not just an empty string. Hoping that Dropwizard would automatically use the decorator and return 400 for such a request.

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.5/docs/manual/validation.html#optional-t-constraints

Answer (score 1):

The `JSR-380` spec (Bean Validation 2.0) considers empty optionals to be `null`.

Therefore; if you use a constraint that checks for null (such as `@NotBlank` or `@NotEmpty`) you should get the desired behaviour:

```
Optional<@NotBlank String> voice;
```

or

```
Optional<@NotEmpty String> voice;
```

I would suggest using `@NotBlank` if you want to check the trimmed String.  `" "` (whitespace) will pass `@NotEmpty` but not `@NotBlank`.

If you use a constraint that **does not** check for null (most constraints), then simply adding the `@NotNull` constraint should do the trick. I've not tested this though.

```
Optional<@NotNull @Size(min = 1, max = 1000) String> voice;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `@NotEmpty` then why use `Optional`. You can add validation method for this.

Add this validation method in your request class:

```
@AssertTrue
    public boolean isValid(){
        return StringUtils.isNotBlank(voice.orElse(null));
    }
```